# Nested namespace deletion

Tags: python, namespaces, maya

I am scripting to remove namespaces (nested or un-nested) without the use/opening of the Namespace Editor, assuming the criteria is fulfilled where there are no contents within them.

While doing so, I got into this problem where I am unable to delete nested namespace using `cmds.namespace(rm="<string of the namespace>")`

I have sort of found a longer workaround but I am stuck as the output was unicode in a list and I cannot seem to convert it into string.

```
nsLs = cmds.namespaceInfo( lon=True)
# nsLs Result: [u'UI', u'camera01',  u'shared', u'v02', u'v03']

defaultNs = ["UI", "shared", "camera01"]

diffLs = [item for item in nsLs if item not in defaultNs]
# diffLs Result: [u'v02', u'v03']

for ns in diffLs:
    nsNest = cmds.namespaceInfo(ns, lon=True)
    # nsNest Result:    [u'v02:new_run01']
    #                   [u'v03:new_run01']
    cmds.namespace(rm=str(nsNest))
```

As such, the 'remove' flag I have used is not working as the following error is encountered:

```
# Error: No namespace matches name: '[u'v02:new_run01']'.
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 13, in <module>
# RuntimeError: No namespace matches name: '[u'v02:new_run01']'. #
```

The above code I have inputted is solely for the nested namespaces, though it is still not 'there' to achieve the results and not very flexible either (assuming that within the scene there is only 1 nested level), are there any ways to rectify this?

Additionally, appreciate if anyone have any solutions/methods for deleting namespaces without the use if the Namespace Editor, of course...

[image: nestedNs]

Answer (score 0):

Where the `namespace` command expects a string (in this case `'v02:new_run01'`), you are passing it the stringified list itself (in this case `'[u'v02:new_run01']'`). Since you have `lon=True` flag, the command will always return a list. You should make sure you extract the element from it and send it to the `namespace` command.

All you have to do is pass the element from the list instead of the whole list:

```
for ns in diffLs:
    nsNest = cmds.namespaceInfo(ns, lon=True)
    # nsNest Result:    [u'v02:new_run01']
    #                   [u'v03:new_run01']
    if nsNest:
        cmds.namespace(rm=nsNest[0])
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It is working. Was wondering if you know any ways to determine the nested levels of the namespaces?

Comment: Post it here then. And consider voting up if you found the answer helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is the following code in which it deletes any levels of the nested namespaces, assuming that it is holding empty contents.

```
import maya.cmds as mc

defaults = ['UI', 'shared']

def num_children(ns):
    return ns.count(':')

namespaces = [ns for ns in mc.namespaceInfo(lon=True, r=True) if ns not in defaults]
sorted_ns = sorted(namespaces, key=num_children, reversed=True)
for ns in sorted_ns:
    try:
        mc.namespace(rm=ns)
    except RuntimeError as e:
        pass
```

Thanks to a particular friend who helps out on this :)

Answer (score 0):

To delete all the [namespaces](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/PyMel/generated/functions/pymel.core.system/pymel.core.system.namespace.html?highlight=namespace#pymel-core-system-namespace) you probably need to use **recurse** and **mergeNamespaceWithParent** flags. That way it'll delete all the namespaces and will parent it to root.

```
# Gathering and deleting all namespaces
name_space = [item for item in pm.namespaceInfo(lon=True, recurse=True) if item not in ["UI", "shared"]]
# Sort them from child to parent, That's order we need to delete
sorted_ns_namespace = sorted(name_space, key=lambda ns: ns.count(':'), reverse=True)

for ns in sorted_ns_namespace:
    pm.namespace(removeNamespace=ns, mergeNamespaceWithParent=True)
```